# Conditional rendering in React based on state

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, state

I'm sending an API request and render its result in to UI.

Now, for the error-handling, I wanted that if there is an error a div which contains an error message gets rendered in to the UI.

To achieve this I wrote the following ternary condition:

```
const showError = this.state.error
? `<div className="error-container">
    Error:
      <p>{this.state.error}</p>
   </div>`
: '';
```

And then used this inside my render method: `{showError}`

But React see the result as a string and renders the following to the UI:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In you `render` method you can do following:

```
render() {
  return(
   // ... other components
   {this.state.error && (
     <div className="error-container">
       Error:
       <p>{this.state.error}</p>
     </div>
    )}
    // ... 
  )
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks. I wasn't aware of this method. What is it called?

Comment: It is `Inline If with Logical && Operator` You can check it https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that you made `showError` a string by wrapping the content within ``(backticks) and it no longer remains a JSX expression

Use `()` instead. Also when you don't want to return anything, you should return `null` instead of an empty string

```
const showError = this.state.error
? (<div className="error-container">
    Error:
      <p>{this.state.error}</p>
   </div>)
: '';
```