# React rendering based on boolean in state: ternary not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, conditional-operator

React Dev Tools shows me that the state is successfully changing, however the correct component is not rendering.

Here's the ternary inside a button that toggles state:

```
return (
  <div>
    <div>{questionBlocks}</div>
    <button className="advanced-options" onClick={this.toggleAdvanced}>
      {this.state.advancedText}
      <span>
        {this.showAdvanced ? <ExpandLessIcon /> : <ExpandMoreIcon />}
      </span>
    </button>
  </div>
);
```

Here's the toggleAdvanced function (that's working perfectly, as I am successfully showing new elements on toggling showAdvanced:

```
toggleAdvanced = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.showAdvanced === true) {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        showAdvanced: !prevState.showAdvanced,
      }));
    } else {
     this.setState((prevState) => ({
       showAdvanced: !prevState.showAdvanced,
      }));
    }
};
```

Looked at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54733707/conditional-rendering-in-react-based-on-state) [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58243683/conditional-rendering-based-on-state), amongst others, but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `state` in the ternary. It should be `this.state.showAdvanced`, not `this.showAdvanced`.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is probably here

```
  <span>
        {this.showAdvanced ? <ExpandLessIcon /> : <ExpandMoreIcon />}
      </span>
```

You are using `this.showAdvanced` but it should be `this.state.showAdvanced`